# Are Facebook and Path using an open source library for their root navigation UI?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, three20

The latest update to Path includes a root navigation UI that is strikingly similar to the one Facebook included in v4 of their app a few months ago. Is there an open source version of this implementation or did Path build it from scratch? It doesn't appear that Three20 got an update from what I can see in their documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few people who have achieved this in open source code on github, here is one I found that looks good: https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo

Answer (score 2):

Try this. it basically replaces a typical uinavigationcontroller and adds that functionality. 
http://github.com/drunknbass/DNBSwipyNavigationController